# How to access entity inside of another entity in twig?

Tags: php, twig, redbean

I have two tables:

**Key**

- id
- hook
- cupboard

**History**

- date
- action
- key

How do I access `key` inside of the `history` entity in Twig?

`{{ history.key.hook }}` does not seem to work?

`{{ dump(history) }}` provides this:

```
object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean)#120 (10) { ["properties":protected]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["date"]=> string(19) "2018-12-06 16:06:21" ["action"]=> string(6) "Issued" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["key_id"]=> string(2) "17" } ["__info":protected]=> array(7) { ["type"]=> string(7) "history" ["sys.id"]=> string(2) "id" ["sys.orig"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["date"]=> string(19) "2018-12-06 16:06:21" ["action"]=> string(6) "Issued" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["key_id"]=> string(2) "17" } ["tainted"]=> bool(false) ["changed"]=> bool(false) ["changelist"]=> array(0) { } ["model"]=> NULL } ["beanHelper":protected]=> object(RedBeanPHP\BeanHelper\SimpleFacadeBeanHelper)#28 (0) { } ["fetchType":protected]=> NULL ["withSql":protected]=> string(0) "" ["withParams":protected]=> array(0) { } ["aliasName":protected]=> NULL ["via":protected]=> NULL ["noLoad":protected]=> bool(false) ["all":protected]=> bool(false) }
```

Comment: No need to show the tables, rather, show us the entities.

Comment: Your entities should contain relation between key <=> history, then getters/setters, and you will be able to do that. Show us your entities.

Comment: Oh I had no idea I have to create a relationship. Should I do in in my database?

Comment: Which frameworks are you using to fetch the data from your database?

Comment: Custom one. https://github.com/rivets/framework2

Comment: Well at least do a `{{ dump(history) }}` then to give us some insights how your data was fetched

Comment: I edited my question with the output

Comment: Ok seems `redbean` is the ORM that is beiing used. Did you create a foreign key towards the table  `key`

Comment: Does your key entity have an ownHistoryList (one to many) or a sharedHistoryList (many to many) property? This is the typical redbean convention for model mappings